# What information is recorded in the azcopy log PERF lines?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

As documented in [the wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/wiki/Disk-and-service-constraint-indicators-in-AzCopy#note-on-use-of-log-files-and-brief-tips-on-debugging-other-performance-issues-not-covered-above) AzCopy generates `PERF` lines in its logs to record various elements of the application state.

Here as an extract from an upload job:

```
2023/08/11 04:49:48 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: X:  0, O:  0, M:  0, L:  0, R:  0, D:  1, W: 94, F:  0, B: 63, E:  0, T: 158, GRs: 64
2023/08/11 04:49:50 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: X:  0, O:  0, M:  0, L:  0, R:  0, D:  1, W: 55, F:  0, B: 63, E:  0, T: 119, GRs: 64
2023/08/11 04:49:52 PERF: primary performance constraint is Disk. States: X:  0, O:  0, M:  0, L:  0, R:  0, D:  1, W:  7, F:  0, B: 63, E:  0, T: 71, GRs: 64
2023/08/11 04:49:54 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: X:  0, O:  0, M:  0, L:  0, R:  0, D:  0, W:  0, F:  0, B: 16, E:  0, T: 16, GRs: 64
2023/08/11 04:49:56 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: X:  0, O:  0, M:  0, L:  0, R:  0, D:  0, W:  0, F:  0, B:  0, E:  0, T:  0, GRs: 64
```

And an extract from a download job:

```
2023/08/18 09:04:54 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R: 64, W: 1507, F:  0, H:  0, B: 16, S:  0, P:  8, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T: 1595, GRs: 16
2023/08/18 09:04:56 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R: 64, W: 1513, F:  0, H:  1, B: 15, S:  0, P:  4, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T: 1597, GRs: 16
2023/08/18 09:04:58 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R: 64, W: 1514, F:  0, H:  1, B: 15, S:  0, P:  1, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T: 1595, GRs: 16
2023/08/18 09:05:00 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R: 64, W: 1512, F:  0, H:  1, B: 15, S:  0, P:  4, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T: 1596, GRs: 16
2023/08/21 02:01:15 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R:  0, W:  0, F:  0, H:  0, B:  0, S:  0, P:  0, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T:  0, GRs: 16
```

There is clearly a large amount of data being recorded here but unfortunately as far as I can tell the wiki doesn't document what each of these fields represent.

Is this information known and available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The file that you have shared can be breakdown as given below:

I have taken reference from one of the line also stated below:

```
2023/08/18 09:04:54 PERF: primary performance constraint is Unknown. States: C:  0, R: 64, W: 1507, F:  0, H:  0, B: 16, S:  0, P:  8, Q:  0, D:  0, E:  0, T: 1595, GRs: 16
```

- **Date and Time**: `2023/08/18 09:04:54` - This is the date and time when the log entry was generated.
- **Message Type**: `PERF` - This indicates that the log entry is related to performance metrics.
- **Primary Performance Constraint**: `Unknown` - In this context, it states that the primary performance constraint is unknown. This could mean that `azcopy` is not able to determine the primary limiting factor affecting performance.
- **States**:

  - **C: 0** - Number of Concurrency (parallel operations) currently active.
  - **R: 64** - Number of HTTP Requests (usually indicating read operations).
  - **W: 1507** - Number of Write (upload) operations.
  - **F: 0** - Number of Failed operations.
  - **H: 0** - Number of OnHold operations.
  - **B: 16** - Number of Buffers (part of internal caching mechanisms).
  - **S: 0** - Number of Scheduled (pending) operations.
  - **P: 8** - Number of Pipelines (concurrent transfer channels).
  - **Q: 0** - Number of Queued operations.
  - **D: 0** - Number of Dispatched (started) operations.
  - **E: 0** - Number of Executing operations.
  - **T: 1595** - Total number of operations performed.
  - **GRs: 16** - Number of Get Responses (usually indicating read operations).

Comment: Thanks @Chirag, this is very helpful.  Do you have any information on X, O, M, and L from the upload logs?

Comment: This generates out of custom metric, my apologies not sure on X,O,M and L